# c#, Changing program to linear search

Tags: c#, replace, linear-search

I made this code a couple of days ago and have a pretty simple question. I know questions like this have been asked, but I couldn't find anything that specifically works for my case. I want to change the search function in case 3 to a less complex search method, so I basically want to replace it with linear search. If that is not possible I want to implement the linear search somewhere else. You guys have any clues? All help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Loggbok
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime tiden = DateTime.UtcNow;//Skriver ut tiden vid varje inlägg
            bool running = true;//Ger ett booleskt värde till variabeln running för att kunna skapa en loop
            List<string[]> loggbok = new List<string[]>();//Här skapas listan som innehåller arrayen

        while (running)//Här skapas loopen
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("\nVälkommen till loggboken!");
            Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("\n[1] Skriv nytt inlägg i loggboken");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] Skriv ut alla loggar");
            Console.WriteLine("[3] Sök inlägg i loggboken");
            Console.WriteLine("[4] Radera innehåll i loggboken");
            Console.WriteLine("[5] Avsluta loggboken");
            Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
            Console.Write("\nVälj: ");

            int option;//Int eftersom valet ska vara ett heltal

            try
            {
                option = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//testar så att inmatningen är av typen Int

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fel, du får bara skriva in nummer");//Felmeddelande om inmatningen är en bokstav
                continue;
            }

            switch (option)
            {
                case 1:
                    string[] logg = new string[2];//Här deklareras arrayen
                    Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
                    Console.WriteLine(tiden);
                    Console.WriteLine("Ange en Titel:");
                    logg[0] = Console.ReadLine();//Här sparas titeln
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv inlägg:");
                    logg[1] = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Console.ReadLine(), Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));//Här sparas inlägget samt datum och tid, detta är möjligt tack vare formattering 
                    loggbok.Add(logg);
                    break;


                case 2:
                    foreach (string[] item in loggbok)//För att skriva ut alla items i loggboken
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------\n ");
                        Console.WriteLine(item[0]);//För att skriva ut titel
                        Console.WriteLine(item[1]);//För att skriva ut inlägg
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------\n ");
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;




                case 3:

                    Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ett ord du vill söka efter i loggboken:");
                    var nyckelord = Console.ReadLine();//Här sparas inmatningen av nyckelordet
                    var entries = loggbok.Where(entry => entry.Any(item =>item.IndexOf(nyckelord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1));//För att kontrollera om nyckelordet finns samt ignorera skiftlägeskänslighet, och finna både titel och inlägg
                    foreach (var entry in entries)//för att finna alla inlägg/titlar som matchar nyckelord
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------\n ");
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", entry));//Skriver ut titel samt inlägg som matchat nyckelordet
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------\n ");
                    }
                    if (entries.Count() == 0)//Om ingen matchning hittas
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------\n ");
                        Console.Write("Din sökning misslyckades...");//Felmeddelande om ingen matchning hittas
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------\n ");
                    }
                    break;



                case 4:

                    Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv titeln på det inlägg du vill ta bort:");
                    string title = Console.ReadLine();//Sparar titeln på inlägget användaren vill radera

                    for (int x = 0; x < loggbok.Count; x++) //Loopa igenom varje titel
                    {
                        if (String.Equals(loggbok[x][0], title, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) //Icke skiftlägeskänslig matchning av titeln.
                        {
                            loggbok.RemoveAt(x); //Matchning funnen.
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Titeln finns inte, återgår till huvudmenyn");
                        }


                    }
                    break; //Avsluta loopen.


                case 5:

                    running = false;//Avslutar loopen och därmed programmet
                    break;


                default:

                    Console.WriteLine("Nu blev det fel, välj mellan [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]");//Felmeddelande om valet är någon annan siffra än de som menyn innehåller
                    break;









            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There's a lot more code here than necessary - can you trim it down to just the part you want to simplify?

Comment: The only rellevant part seems to be the line starting with `var entries = loggbok.Where(`. The search looks pretty simple. What do you want to simplify?

Comment: I want the program to look like this in this part. The only error I'm getting is: use of unassigned local variable logg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your keyword search in case 3 is already linear. Are you just trying to make the search statement less verbose inside the switch? Then turn the search expression into a function:

```
static IEnumerable<string[]> SearchByKeyword(IEnumerable<string[]> loggbok,
  string nyckelord) {
  return loggbok.Where(entry => entry
    .Any(item => item.IndexOf(nyckelord, 
      StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1));
}
```

and invoke it in the switch statement:

```
var entries = SearchByKeyword(loggbok, nyckelord);
```

Comment: The great thing about a helper function is that someday you could switch it to use a keyword index instead of slow linear search, and the main program wouldn't have to change at all, it would just get faster.